# Algebraic closure as directed colimit

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, limits-colimits

In the spirit of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665044) question:

Can be proved the existence of an algebraic closure of a field by building it as directed colimit of an explicit (simple) diagram of fields?

Comment: I think you always have to use all the finite subextensions of the algebraic closure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't assume the existence of an algebraic closure. I edit my question.